# Am I mutating state in React? Filtering 24 hours of data into smaller datasets with client side filtering

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I'm building a "live" booking map to render map markers every time my company gets a booking.  I'm using node-postgres to query our database every 5 minutes and then pass the results down as JSON to Mapbox gl js library React-Map-Gl...and then fire off animations with GSAP to simulate real-time rendering of the map markers.

I put "live" in quotes because recently we've experienced significant database lag, and throughout the day the map data could be 2, 4, even 8 hours behind...had to write some extra code to get the past 24 hours of booking data, and break it into smaller chunks like past 5, 15, 30 minutes, 1 hr, 2 hr etc. When the data fetch is complete, within that function the map knows which data set to use with conditional logic.

HERE'S THE BUG I'M TRYING TO SOLVE:

I've built a component to allow the user to select which data set they want they see, via radio button input field. Each one has a method built to select the appropriate data set and pass props down to the map component. Works great...on the first click! But if you click another data set, and then go back to one that was previously selected the app crashes? Any ideas?

I've set an initial state of onTheMap: [] in my constructor (haven't tried this with hooks yet, it's a class component). To break up the data into chunks, Inside my data fetch method I've got several filter functions running like so:

```
const rn = Date.now();
//apiData is the entire data set of 24hrs...
const past5MinBkgs = apiData.filter(bkg => {
//rn is the current time in milliseconds since epoch (1/1/1970), minus
//5mins times 60k milliseconds, or the number of milliseconds in a minute...
return new Date(bkg.timestamp) >= rn - 5 * 60000;
//returns out those bookings whose timestamps fit the timeframe.
});
```

After this, a block of conditional logic (Still inside of data fetch method) determines which one has data to compensate for db lag...

```
if (past5MinBkgs.length > 0) {
    this.setState({ onTheMap: past5MinBkgs,});
    console.log("Loading past 5 mins");
} else if (past15MinBkgs.length > 0) {
this.setState({onTheMap: past15MinBkgs,});
console.log("Loading past 15 mins");
}
...
```

And finally I set the state for all of these data sets...

```
this.setState({
past5minBkgs,
past15minBkgs,
etc.
)};
```

#### **Here is the method(s) that is failing:**

```
handleData5Min = () => {
        this.setState({
            onTheMap: this.state.past5MinBkgs
            
        });
    };
```

This method works! but only if 5mins has not been previously selected? For example, if there is no database lag, it will default to the 5 minute data set. User clicks the radio button which calls the 'handleData1hrBkgs" method - no problem! User then clicks the radio button to "handleData5min" and the app crashes?!?

With the handleData... methods as such, the error I get is from the GSAP animation library "Cannot tween a null target" and I think the animation timeline is firing before the setState call is complete...but why would this only happen the 2nd time a data set is called? has that array been mutated when it was originally told it was now "onTheMap" ? I've tried a few things using spread operators etc but haven't gotten to the finish line yet on this one - any ideas to make it work all the time?

EDIT: Per request of @Minwork, here is the full js file (trimmed off some the fat, but there's still over 200 lines of code here to digest...thanks for the help!!!)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

//components
import LiveWorldBookingsMap from "./liveBookingsWorld";  // <-react-map-gl
import Loading from "../../animations/loading/loading";

class WorldLiveBookingMapContainer extends Component {
    liveBookingIntervalID;
    _isMounted = false;
    state = {
        apiData: [],
        onTheMap: [],
        nowShowing: "",
        past1MinBkgs: [],
        past5MinBkgs: [],
        past15MinBkgs: [],
        fetchFreq: 5 * 60, //frequency, in seconds, of data fetch
        loading: false
        };
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getWorldBookingData();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.liveBookingIntervalID);
    }
    getWorldBookingData = () => {
        this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
            //get the data, then re-format into JSON
            //data is stored as const apiData
                const rn = Date.now();
                const past1MinBkgs = apiData.filter(bkg => {
                    return new Date(bkg.timestamp) >= rn - 1 * 60000;
                });
                const past5MinBkgs = apiData.filter(bkg => {
                    return new Date(bkg.timestamp) >= rn - 5 * 60000;
                });
                const past15MinBkgs = apiData.filter(bkg => {
                    return new Date(bkg.timestamp) >= rn - 15 * 60000;
                });
                            
                //Loads the most recent dataset greater than 0 on to the map
                if (past1MinBkgs.length > 0) {
                    this.setState({
                        onTheMap: past1MinBkgs,
                        nowShowing: "Past 1 min"
                    });
                    console.log("Loading past 1 min");
                } else if (past5MinBkgs.length > 0) {
                    this.setState({
                        onTheMap: past5MinBkgs,
                        nowShowing: "Past 5 mins"
                    });
                    console.log("Loading past 5 mins");
                } else if (past15MinBkgs.length > 0) {
                    this.setState({
                        onTheMap: past15MinBkgs,
                        nowShowing: "Past 15 mins"
                    });
                    console.log("Loading past 15 mins");
                } 
                    
                // If a data set is 0, disable the input so the user can't select it
                if (past5MinBkgs.length === 0) {
                    this.setState({ disabled5minInput: true });
                }
                if (past15MinBkgs.length === 0) {
                    this.setState({ disabled15minInput: true });
                }
                this.setState({
                    apiData,
                    past1MinBkgs,
                    past5MinBkgs,
                    past15MinBkgs,
                    loading: false
                });
            });
            //recursively calls function on an interval so it gets more data
            //set to run every 5 minutes, or this.state.fetchFreq
            this.liveBookingIntervalID = setTimeout(
                this.getWorldBookingData.bind(this),
                this.state.fetchFreq * 1000
            );
        });
    };
    //not working nut dn crash...causes component to unmount?
    handleData1Min = () => {
        let onTheMap = [...this.state.onTheMap];
        onTheMap.splice(this.state.past1MinBkgs);
        this.setState({
            onTheMap,
            nowShowing: "Past 1 min"
        });
    };
    //works...but if 15min has been previously selected, crashes
    handleData5Min = () => {
        this.setState({
            onTheMap: this.state.past5MinBkgs,
            timelineDelay: 5 * 60,
            nowShowing: "Past 15 mins"
        });
    };
    handleData15Min = () => {
        this.setState({
            onTheMap: this.state.past15MinBkgs,
            timelineDelay: 5 * 60,
            nowShowing: "Past 15 mins"
        });
        //if I console.log this.state.past15MinBkgs, still logs?
    };
    
    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            //renders loading animation if data fetch in progress
            return <Loading />;
        } else if (this.state.onTheMap.length > 0) {
            return (
                <div className="worldLiveBookingMapContainer">
                    <Grid container spacing={0} alignContent="center" justify="center">
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <div className="mapboxContainer">
                                <LiveWorldBookingsMap
                                    onTheMap={this.state.onTheMap}
                                    fetchFreq={this.state.fetchFreq}
                                />

                                <div
                                    className="expandCardContainer-mapBookings"
                                    style={{ right: 545, top: 17 }}>
                                    <MapBookingsExpandCard
                                        headerIcon={<BookingsToggleIcon />}
                                        headerText={"Data Selector"}
                                        headerColor={"#afafaf"}
                                        body={
                                            <>
                                                <h4 style={{ maxWidth: "250px" }}>
                                                    Select which data set <br />
                                                    you want to see:
                                                </h4>
                                                <ul className="dataSelectorList">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <input
                                                            className="radioStyle"
                                                            type="radio"
                                                            value="1min"
                                                            name="dataSelector"
                                                            onChange={this.handleData1Min}
                                                        />
                                                        <strong>Past 1 min:</strong>{" "}
                                                        {this.state.past1MinBkgs.length}
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <input
                                                            className="radioStyle"
                                                            type="radio"
                                                            value="5min"
                                                            name="dataSelector"
                                                            disabled={this.state.disabled5minInput}
                                                            onChange={this.handleData5Min}
                                                        />
                                                        <strong>Past 5 mins:</strong>{" "}
                                                        {this.state.past5MinBkgs.length}
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <input
                                                            className="radioStyle"
                                                            type="radio"
                                                            value="15min"
                                                            name="dataSelector"
                                                            disabled={this.state.disabled15minInput}
                                                            // checked={false} //now its not checked even when selected?
                                                            onChange={this.handleData15Min}
                                                        />
                                                        <strong>Past 15 mins:</strong>{" "}
                                                        {this.state.past15MinBkgs.length}
                                                    </li>
                                                    
                                                </ul>
                                                <p>
                                                    <em>
                                                        Defaults to 5 minute delay
                                                        <br />
                                                        or most recent data set.
                                                        <br />
                                                        Refreshes every 5 minutes.
                                                    </em>
                                                </p>
                                            </>
                                        }
                                    />
                                </div>
                                
                                <h3
                                    style={{
                                        position: "absolute",
                                        right: 20,
                                        top: 9,
                                        color: "white",
                                        backgroundColor: "#afafaf",
                                        borderRadius: "30px",
                                        padding: "5px 12px 7px 12px"
                                    }}>
                                    <strong>Showing:</strong> <em>{this.state.nowShowing}</em>
                                </h3>
                                
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </div>
            );
        } else return null;
    }
}

export default WorldLiveBookingMapContainer;
```

Comment: Just pinging in comment so you will see it in notifications and check out my reworked answer based on code you supplied.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your whole code I think I found the source of the problem and it is right here:

```js
let onTheMap = [...this.state.onTheMap];
onTheMap.splice(this.state.past1MinBkgs);
```

don't know what exactly you wanted to accomplish by doing this two lines of code but you are using `splice` (check [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)) function in a wrong way. It should take start index as first argument, then how many elements should be deleted and **then list of items**.

But as I said I don't know what you trying to do here. Because if you just want to append `this.state.past1MinBkgs` elements to the `onTheMap` array you can just use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements

Comment: Unforunately this solution gave me the same error.  Getting closer with this below - which dn crash but the component unmounts and you need to refresh the browser? I think it supports what you are saying that I am overwriting the original data set...
```
 handleData5Min = () => {
  let onTheMap = [...this.state.onTheMap];
  onTheMap.splice(this.state.past5MinBkgs);
  this.setState({
   onTheMap
   
   
  });
 };
```

Comment: @UnionInDesign Can you paste whole code of your component? It would be much easier to locate the source of an error.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't quite arrived at the answer, I wanted to add an update to the post and reframe the question, as well as a link to where you can see a working code demo on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lzbh3m  (Feel free to visit the repo too: https://github.com/Unionindesign/react-mapbox-animated-world-map)

I've narrowed down the issue a bit more - **the crash is (I believe) due to refs being called twice on updating, with the first call being null, hence my GSAP error for the animations "cannot tween a null target"**...there may still be an issue about mutating state or the error:

> "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props
>   and state."

Per the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

> If the ref callback is defined as an inline function, it will get called twice during updates, first with null and then again with the DOM element. This is because a new instance of the function is created with each render, so React needs to clear the old ref and set up the new one. You can avoid this by defining the ref callback as a bound method on the class, but note that it shouldn’t matter in most cases.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
I am using an inline function ref callback to the dom nodes I am trying to animate, which you can see in the stackblitz file map.js on lines 241 and 261.

Here's a snippet:

```
  {this.props.onTheMap.map((city, i) => (
    <Marker
        key={i}
        latitude={city.latitude}
        longitude={city.longitude}
        offsetLeft={-20}
        offsetTop={-10}>
              <div className="markerContainer">
              <div className="markerPopup" 
              //not working...
              //ref={this.setPopupRef}
              ref={e => (this.markerPopups[i] = e)}>
                <h4 className="markerHeader">{city.city}
                  <span onClick={this.handleClosePopup(i)}>
                      <CloseIcon />
                    </span>
                </h4>
                <hr />
                <ul>
                  <li>Population: {(city.population).toLocaleString()}</li> 
                  <li>State: {city.state}</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
             <svg onClick={this.handleOpenPopup(i)} className="mapMarker">
                <circle
                    cx={12}
                    cy={12}
                    //show larger radius marker based on population
                    r={this.markersizer(city.population)}
                    //not working...
                    //ref={this.setMarkerRef}
                    //working
                    ref={e => (this.MapMarkers[i] = e)}
                        style={{
                            fill: "red",
                            stroke: "#FFF",
                            strokeWidth: 2
                            }}
                        />
              </svg>
            </div>
        </Marker>
                    ))}
```

I've attempted to follow the recommendation in the docs by creating a bound method on the class - this works...ish? I am able to select any data set, multiple times, with no crash...but the refs always return undefined and as the result the animations won't start? I'm also posting this in GSAP forums, but if anyone has any ideas on the React-side of things let me know!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**
Like most fixes it was a one-liner - but man! Tricky business dealing with refs!

So here's what happens:

- If you are using refs with an inline function to animate an array of DOM elements...which seems to be the best method to get GSAP animations working within your class component (tried createRef API...this either didn't work to pass DOM elements as animation targets...or was not well setup to create an array of them if there are more than one...haven't tried useRef?), you'll be in hot water if you update your component!

> If the ref callback is defined as an inline function, it will get called twice during updates, first with null and then again with the DOM element.

If you console.log("Refs: " + this.myREf); your refs before and after the update...at least in my case...is that you get back what looks like an array of arrays like

```
[object SVGCircleElement],
[object SVGCircleElement],
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

While the react docs suggest that the ref callback inline function is being called twice, once with null values and then with the actual DOM elements (in this case an SVG circle used for map markers), to me it looks more like the null values are appended to the end of the array?

Enter loDash! I tried many array methods like _.isEmpty, _.isNull, to check for (and remove) null values, and also _.pick, _.pickBy (picks the stuff you specify from the array) similar to _.omit and _.omitBy (per the docs these take longer but basically do the same thing). All of the above methods return a new array, which in my case would somehow mutate the ref? The DOM elements were not preserved and the animations would not work.

**This worked! _.compact <-- removes falsey values of any kind from your array, without returning a new array so the original one is intact!**

In the odd circumstance someone runs into a same/similar error, add this to your animation code (and be sure to import _  from "lodash" of course)

```
const myAnimationTargets = _.compact(this.myArrayOfRefsToDomNodes)
```

Should work! At least until callback refs become deprecated like string refs did...hopefully that doesn't happen for a while!